# keyboard layout language is not detectable

Tags: keyboard, language

I cant find the keyboard language from the list suggested or the detection mechanism (assign english).

apparently it is english yet no english version from the list is compatible.

this is how it is:

a z e r t y u i o p [{ ]} |\

q s d f g h j k l m '" enter

w x c v b n ;: ,< .> ?/ shift

if i cant find it, can i somehow customize it.

Comment: This is not an English layout; it's probably French. English layout keyboards typically start with "QWERTY", not "AZERTY" on the top row.

Comment: no it's english with 3 keys swapped

Comment: The layout in your question is AZERTY:
http://www.elvastower.com/forums/uploads/monthly_04_2017/post-9029-0-93901000-1491511427_thumb.jpg

AZERTY keyboards are not used in English countries (US, UK, etc...). AZERTY keyboards are typically used in France and Belgium etc

Comment: yes azerty, but there's no letters of other languages, plus the keys with words are in english. it's pretty rare case. hacking into the keymap file in linux solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while i had 3 keys swapped, so i changed the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`

Comment: I ended up, changing the -Physical- keys in the keyboard, I didn't like the inconsistency among my keyboards.